# How to get a user's Instagram feed

Tags: php, instagram

I'd like to get a user's Instagram feed using PHP.  I've signed up for an Instagram Developer Account and tried pulling in a user's info and photos, but the response isn't stable.  Sometimes I get a response and other times I keep getting the error: access_token is missing.  Is there a solid example of getting a user's feed of photos by username?

Ideally, I'd like it to be as simple as:

```
$instagram = new Instagram();
$photos = $instagram->getPhotos("username-goes-here");
```

Where Instagram is a class that handles all the requests.  Any help or direction is appreciated.  Thanks!

Comment: Instagram API changed a lot and other answers don't work anymore. I found the following step by step tutorial very useful to retrieve an Instagram feed https://www.codeofaninja.com/2015/01/display-instagram-feed-website.html

Answer (score 56):

Try this,

```
<?php

  function fetchData($url){
  $ch = curl_init();
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 20);
  $result = curl_exec($ch);
  curl_close($ch); 
  return $result;
  }

  $result = fetchData("https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/ID-GOES-HERE/media/recent/?access_token=TOKEN-GOES-HERE");
  $result = json_decode($result);
  foreach ($result->data as $post) {
    // Do something with this data.
  }
?>
```

May this help you.

Comment: It works for me but, only on production enviroment. For some reason, localhost request is empty.

Comment: To be able to test it in sandbox environment, you need to add test users to your app in Instagram as sandbox users.

Comment: Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in

Comment: It will only show 20 because of the sandbox mode. You will need to go live in order to show more.

Comment: I'm trying to test this on my localhost, but self assigned certificates are not accepted. Instagram apparently no longer allow get api data to none ssl connections... am I right?

Comment: I'm getting this error cURL Error #60: SSL certificate problem: unable to get local issuer certificate

Answer (score 8):

I did this:

```
<?php

  function fetchData($url){
  $ch = curl_init();
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 20);
  $result = curl_exec($ch);
  curl_close($ch); 
  return $result;
  }

  $result = fetchData("https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/USER ID HERE/media/recent/?access_token=ACCES TOKEN HERE&count=14");


  $result = json_decode($result);
  foreach ($result->data as $post) {
     if(empty($post->caption->text)) {
       // Do Nothing
     }
     else {
        echo '<a class="instagram-unit" target="blank" href="'.$post->link.'">
        <img src="'.$post->images->low_resolution->url.'" alt="'.$post->caption->text.'" width="100%" height="auto" />
        <div class="instagram-desc">'.htmlentities($post->caption->text).' | '.htmlentities(date("F j, Y, g:i a", $post->caption->created_time)).'</div></a>';
     }

  }
?>
```

Answer (score 5):

Taking what i have seen around the internet and on this page, I have created an Instagram class (very simple, only for pulling feed, etc.') below.

```
class Instagram {
    public static $result;
    public static $display_size = 'thumbnail'; // you can choose between "low_resolution", "thumbnail" and "standard_resolution"
    public static $access_token = "DEFAULTACCESSTOKEN"; // default access token, optional
    public static $count = 10;
    public static function fetch($url){
        $ch = curl_init();
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 20);
        $result = curl_exec($ch);
        curl_close($ch);
        return $result;
    }
    function __construct($Token=null){
        if(!empty($Token)){
            self::$access_token = $Token;

            // Remove from memory -- not sure if really needed.
            $Token = null;
            unset($Token);
        }
        self::$result = json_decode(self::fetch("https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/self/media/recent?count=" . self::$count . "&access_token=" . self::$access_token), true);
    }
}
$Instagram = new Instagram('ACCESSTOKENIFCHANGEDORNULLOREMPTY');
foreach ($Instagram::$result->data as $photo) {
    $img = $photo->images->{$Instagram::$display_size};
}
```

Answer (score 2):

**Update: 15.6.2017 - Instagram has changed the end point, the following does not work anymore.**

Since it's not anymore possible to get random users feed without approved application, I've figured out how to get it using the unofficial API:

```
#!/bin/bash
instagram_user_id=25025320
count=12
csrftoken=$(curl --head -k https://www.instagram.com/ 2>&1 | grep -Po "^Set-Cookie: csrftoken=\K(.*?)(?=;)")
curl "https://www.instagram.com/query/" -H "cookie: csrftoken=$csrftoken;" -H "x-csrftoken: $csrftoken" -H "referer: https://www.instagram.com/" --data "q=ig_user($instagram_user_id)%20%7B%20media.after(0%2C%20$count)%20%7B%0A%20%20count%2C%0A%20%20nodes%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20caption%2C%0A%20%20%20%20code%2C%0A%20%20%20%20comments%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20count%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%2C%0A%20%20%20%20date%2C%0A%20%20%20%20dimensions%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20height%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20width%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%2C%0A%20%20%20%20display_src%2C%0A%20%20%20%20id%2C%0A%20%20%20%20is_video%2C%0A%20%20%20%20likes%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20count%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%2C%0A%20%20%20%20owner%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20id%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20username%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20full_name%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20profile_pic_url%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%2C%0A%20%20%20%20thumbnail_src%2C%0A%20%20%20%20video_views%0A%20%20%7D%2C%0A%20%20page_info%0A%7D%0A%20%7D" -k
```

I will improve this answer with PHP later, I need to do this with PHP too.

Answer (score 2):

Answers should be updated, as now the only possible way is trough Instagram Facebook API --> https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instagram/oembed

Answer (score 1):

Found this medium article:- https://medium.com/@bkwebster/how-to-get-instagram-api-access-token-and-fix-your-broken-feed-c8ad470e3f02

```
 <?php
                    $user_id=xxxxxx;//User ID is the first string of numbers before the first dot (.)
                    $count=2;
                    $width=100;
                    $height=100;
                    $url = 'https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/'.$user_id.'/media/recent/?access_token=xxxxxx.83c3b89.257e2fd9c2bd40c181a2a4fb9576628c&count='.$count;

                    // Also Perhaps you should cache the results as the instagram API is slow
                    $cache = './'.sha1($url).'.json';
                    if(file_exists($cache) && filemtime($cache) > time() - 60*60){
                        // If a cache file exists, and it is newer than 1 hour, use it
                        $jsonData = json_decode(file_get_contents($cache));
                    } else {
                        $jsonData = json_decode((file_get_contents($url)));
                        file_put_contents($cache,json_encode($jsonData));
                    }
                    foreach ($jsonData->data as $key=>$value) {
                        ?>
                        <ul class="w3_footer_grid_list1">
                            <li><label class="fa fa-instagram" aria-hidden="true"></label><a target="_blank" href="<?php echo $value->link;?>"><i><?php echo $value->caption->text; ?> </i></a><?php  ?>
                            </li>
                            <a target="_blank" href="<?php echo $value->link;?>">
                            <img src="<?php echo  $value->images->low_resolution->url;?>" alt="'.$value->caption->text.'" width="<?php echo $width;?>" height="<?php echo $height;?>" />
                            </a>
                        </ul>
                        <?php
                    }
                ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

this function goes in your App class, but can be a regular function and it will work anyways.

```
<?php
    public function instagram(){
      $user = 'your user here';
      // you can get your token from here: https://instagram.pixelunion.net/
      $access_token = 'your access token here';
      $photo_count = 6;// you can choose the amount. 20 is the max per query

      $json_link = "https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/self/media/recent/?";
      $json_link .="access_token={$access_token}&count={$photo_count}";
      $json = file_get_contents($json_link);
      return json_decode($json);
    }
```

the result can be navigated interactively using this tool: http://jsonviewer.stack.hu/

[image: json file returned by the API]

in my case i'm using blade template engine (https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/blade)

so the template will be

```
@foreach($instagram->data as $gram)
   <img src="{{$gram->images->thumbnail->url}}">
@endforeach
```

that's it!

Answer (score -1):

try this one a crawler type in raw form.

```
function feed_instagram($url = "https://www.instagram.com/titaniumheart_")
{  
    //$url ie https://www.instagram.com/titaniumheart_

    $dom = new DOMDocument();
    @$dom->loadHTMLFile($url);
    $f=$dom->saveHTML();  //load the url (crawl)

    $key="";    
    $swquote=0;     
    echo "<div>";

    for ($x=0;$x<strlen($f);$x++)
    {
       $c=substr($f,$x,1);
       //echo $c."-";
        if ($c==chr(34)) 
        {
            if($swquote==0)
            {
                $swquote=1; //to start get chars
            } else
            {
                $swquote=0;
                //echo $key;
                if($key=="code")
                {
                    //get the number of comments
                    $m=substr($f,$x+4,100);
                    $code= substr($m,0,strpos($m,chr(34)));
                    echo "code is ".$code;
                    echo "<br>";
                }               
                if($key=="comments")
                {
                    //get the number of comments
                    $m=substr($f,$x+12,20);
                    $comments= substr($m,0,strpos($m,"}"));
                    echo "number of comments is ".$comments;
                    echo "<br>";
                }
                if($key=="caption")
                {
                    //get the number of comments
                    $m=substr($f,$x+4,200);
                    $caption= substr($m,0,strpos($m,chr(34)));
                    echo "caption is ".$caption;
                    echo "<br>";
                }
                if($key=="likes")
                {
                    //get the number of comments
                    $m=substr($f,$x+12,20);
                    $likes= substr($m,0,strpos($m,"}"));
                    echo "number of likes is ".$likes;
                    echo "<br>";
                }
                if($key=="thumbnail_src")
                {
                    //get the number of comments
                    $m=substr($f,$x+4,200);
                    $src= substr($m,0,strpos($m,"?"));
                    echo "<br>image source is ".$src;
                    echo "<br>";                                    
                    echo "<a href=\"https://www.instagram.com/p/".$code."/\">";
                    echo "<img src=\"".$src."\">";
                    echo "</a><br>";                    
                }                               
               $key="";
        }

    }else
    {
        if($swquote==1)
        {
            $key.=$c;
        }
    }           
}
echo "</div>";
}
```

usage:  https://www.instagram.com/titaniumheart_");?>

take note: you must enabled extension "php_openssl" on php.ini.

Comment: Not using the Instagram API like the user is asking for, this is loading the front end HTML and traversing the DOM.