# How to pull Instagram photos to my blog and integrate with Fancybox?

Tags: php, jquery, api, fancybox, instagram

I saw the docs on the Instagram developers page. http://instagram.com/developer/endpoints/

But I want to display my own photos so I will need to get an access token. After that I want to make my photos work in a Lightbox or Fancybox. I was able to make this work with all endpoints that require a client ID. Its the access token that stumps me.

Edit:

I want to use php and or jquery to create a gallery of images from my account. Can anyone out there point me in the right direction? Are there any tutorials I can use that demonstrate this from start to finish?

Comment: First of all, there is no question in your question.  Second, you haven't tried anything.  If you don't ask a question and show us what you tried, how can we help you?

Comment: I think people are voting this down because it is too vague. It sounds like you haven't even made an attempt.

Comment: I was moreso hoping for someone to point me in the right direction.

Comment: You should rephrase and ask some type of question. Even if it's simply asking if there are any tutorials available.

Comment: Asking for tutorials is a large stretch as well. Try googling first.

Comment: Thanks guys. I will take a few more attempts at this.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I've just written a tutorial to help people like you manipulate this api and generate Fancybox gallery. It even includes source files of the final product. Here is a link http://www.blueprintinteractive.com/blog/how-instagram-api-fancybox-simplified

Comment: Its a great script but you can't cap how many images get pulled in. Its just pulling all of my photos in to my website...What if I want to just display 10?

Comment: You need to use the "count" parameter in the http request. You can see in here http://instagram.com/developer/endpoints/users/#get_users_media_recent

Comment: @Rivers, check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6311195/how-to-get-a-users-instagram-feed/11411110#11411110 , blog admin just cpoy from this answer.

Comment: Thats fine. Doesn't matter to me.

Comment: Sorry for the digging but is it possible to also get just the photos with a matching tag from a specific user?

Comment: Yes. One way would be to pull all photos from a user and iterate through them. I don't know if you can specifically query a user's feed for a certain tag but I haven't looked at this API in a while.