# Instagram async feed

Tags: php, asynchronous, instagram, feed

Following this post [How to get a user's Instagram feed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6311195/how-to-get-a-users-instagram-feed) , i use it to display the last image

```
        function fetchData($url){
        $ch = curl_init();
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 20);
        $result = curl_exec($ch);
        curl_close($ch); 
        return $result;
        }

        $result = fetchData("https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/123456789/media/recent/?access_token=123456789.123asdsd.asdadasdas23423423&count=1");
        $result = json_decode($result);
        foreach ($result->data as $post) {
        if(empty($post->caption->text)) {
        // Do Nothing
        }
        else {
        // Display img
        }
        }
```

How can be loaded asynchronous? Sometimes is takes even 2-3s to load and delays the entire page to be displayed. Tks for you time and help!

Comment: load the output via ajax. Also, consider caching the result for x minutes

Answer (score 1):

**EDIT**
tks to @steve, i solved it by query instagram api once per hour and save the response to instagram.json

get-social-media.php

```
function get_instagram($user_id=instagram_user_id,$count=1){

$instaurl = `https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/`.$user_id.`/media/recent/?access_token=instagram_access_token&count=`.$count;

$instacache = `instagram.json`;
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$instaurl);
$instadata=curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);

if(file_exists($instacache) && filemtime($instacache) > time() - 60*30){
    //echo "ok instagram";
} else {
    $jsonInstaData = json_decode($instadata,true);
    file_put_contents($instacache,json_encode($jsonInstaData));
}
}
echo get_instagram();
```

and that ajax for frontend social-media-block.phtml (magento & bootstrap)

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {  
$("#instagram-img").html("");
$.ajax({  
    type: "GET",  
    async: true,  
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",  
    url:"resources/socialmedia-cache/instagram.json",  
    dataType: "json",  
    cache: true,  
    beforeSend: function () {  
        $("#loading").show();  
    },  
    success: function (data) {  
        console.log(data);  
        $("#loading").hide();  
        if (data == "") {  
            $("#InstaContainer").hide();  
        } else {  
            $("#InstaContainer").show();  

            for (var i = 0; i < data["data"].length; i++) {  
                var dataForJson = JSON.stringify(data.data[i]);  
                var date = new Date(parseInt(data.data[i].caption.created_time) * 1000);  
                $("#instagram-img").append("<a target=`_blank` href=`" + data.data[i].link + "` title=`" + data.data[i].caption.text + "`><img src=`" + data.data[i].images.low_resolution.url + "` class=`img-responsive socialmedia-img`></img></a>");  
                $("#instagram-img").append("<p align=`left`><script>" + "jQuery(document).ready(function() { jQuery(`a.timeago`).timeago();});" + "</" + "script><a class=`timeago` style=`color:#484848;` title=`" +(date.getMonth()+1)+"/"+date.getDate()+"/"+date.getFullYear()+", "+date.getHours()+":"+date.getMinutes()+ "`>" +(date.getMonth()+1)+"/"+date.getDate()+"/"+date.getFullYear()+", "+date.getHours()+":"+date.getMinutes()+ "</a></p>");  
            }  
        }  
    }  
});  
});
```

this also works for facebook
 
for pinterest, i use http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/services/feed/load?v=1.0&num=1&q=https://www.pinterest.com/MyPinterest/feed.rss , a quick solution to convert the rss to json. since i need images larger than 236px, next parsed is 736px. also, the img src needs to be extracted from content

```
var string = data.responseData.feed.entries[i].content;
var filtered = string.replace('/236x/', '/736x/');
var source = filtered.match(/src\s*=\s*"(.+?)"/);
```

probably not the best code, but at least is a working solution.

Comment: I was thinking of a server side cache in php, so in your ajax code, instead of calling the instagram api directly, you call your php code. Your php code  uses curl / file_get_contents to call the api, saves the json to a file,and then echos it. Next time it is called, it checks to see if there is already a file, and if so, if it is not older than xx minutes, it just opens the file and echos the result, instead of making the http request to the api