# Is there a way to pull an instagram feed with PHP without logging in?

Tags: php, instagram

It seems that this solution no longer works -

[How to get a user's Instagram feed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6311195/how-to-get-a-users-instagram-feed)

The new API requires an access token which is dynamically assigned after passing through a login page.  Is there a way to still pull a feed programmatically through PHP without jumping through the new oauth hoops?  This is useful for setting a crontab to automatically save new posts to a database.

Comment: Not without scraping (which is against TOS and a pain to maintain). Just save the token and have your cron use it.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

Yes you can. You don't need to login or access_token to get the latest 20 posts. You just need to parse the json content from `https://www.instagram.com/[USERNAME]/media/`.
Replace the `[username]` with the instagram `user_name`.

eg.

```
$instaResult = file_get_contents('https://www.instagram.com/'.$username.'/media/');
$insta = json_decode($instaResult);
```

UPDATE:
Instagram has changed the user media rss url. In order to get the rss feed you now have to use 
https://www.instagram.com/[USERNAME]/?__a=1

UPDATE:
Instead of `file_get_contents`, it is better to use `curl` or `Psr\Http\Message\RequestInterface` based library like http://docs.guzzlephp.org/en/stable/

Comment: Brilliant!  Where did you ever find this?  Works perfectly

Comment: While this works, it a) may not always work (as it's not part of the public API) and b) is in violation of the TOS, which states "You must not access Instagram's private API by means other than those permitted by Instagram." https://help.instagram.com/478745558852511

Comment: @mmmdearte did you even read my updated. Try using the one with https://www.instagram.com/[USERNAME]/?__a=1 . This solution still works for me.

Comment: Ah yes it works, well done. I, nevertheless, agree with @ceejayoz, it will be a matter of time that Instagram cuts that feed too.

Comment: The new way that you are showing are also no longer working. Its works if you access it normal in the browser but it returns a forbidden status if I use file_get_contents

Comment: This is not longer working (March 30th'20 to be exact)

Answer (score 13):

We can still access the photos. But just last 12 photo. If want more photos access_token require. This my way to get photos.

```
$instaResult = file_get_contents('https://www.instagram.com/'.$username.'/?__a=1');
$insta = json_decode($instaResult);
$instagram_photos = $insta->graphql->user->edge_owner_to_timeline_media->edges;
```

Now we get the last photos array.

Than i used in the view with foreach loop.

```
<ul>
@foreach($instagram_photos as $instagram_photo)
   <li>
       <img src="{{$instagram_photo->node->display_url}}">
   </li>
@endforeach
</ul>
```

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't work anymore. You can open link in the browser but if you try to read it by file_get_contents function instagram will recognized it and serves you html content in the response.

Comment: r.i.p in peace file_get_contents. Say hi to domCrawl.

Answer (score 6):

Try this php library: https://github.com/postaddictme/instagram-php-scraper

And here is example (https://github.com/postaddictme/instagram-php-scraper/blob/master/examples/getAccountMediasByUsername.php):

```
<?php
require __DIR__ . '/../vendor/autoload.php';
// If account is public you can query Instagram without auth
$instagram = new \InstagramScraper\Instagram();
$medias = $instagram->getMedias('kevin', 25);
// Let's look at $media
$media = $medias[0];
echo "Media info:\n";
echo "Id: {$media->getId()}\n";
echo "Shotrcode: {$media->getShortCode()}\n";
echo "Created at: {$media->getCreatedTime()}\n";
echo "Caption: {$media->getCaption()}\n";
echo "Number of comments: {$media->getCommentsCount()}";
echo "Number of likes: {$media->getLikesCount()}";
echo "Get link: {$media->getLink()}";
echo "High resolution image: {$media->getImageHighResolutionUrl()}";
echo "Media type (video or image): {$media->getType()}";
$account = $media->getOwner();
echo "Account info:\n";
echo "Id: {$account->getId()}\n";
echo "Username: {$account->getUsername()}\n";
echo "Full name: {$account->getFullName()}\n";
echo "Profile pic url: {$account->getProfilePicUrl()}\n";
// If account private you should be subscribed and after auth it will be available
$instagram = \InstagramScraper\Instagram::withCredentials('username', 'password', 'path/to/cache/folder');
$instagram->login();
$medias = $instagram->getMedias('private_account', 100);
```

Comment: @PrashantRajpoo it does

Comment: is it still working. The last I tried it keep asking for code or something.