# How do I add Instagram feed in website in PHP?

Tags: javascript, php, instagram-api

i have used this code.

```
<?php foreach ($result->data as $post){ ?>
    <!-- Renders images. @Options (thumbnail,low_resoulution, high_resolution) -->
    <a class="group" rel="group1" href="<?= $post->images->standard_resolution->url ?>"><img src="<?= $post->images->thumbnail->url ?>"></a>
<?php  } ?>
```

I want to add Instagram feed in my website but I am not able to do that please help me with this.

Comment: Have you got any errors?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get Instagram feed like this:

```
<?php

  function fetchData($url){
  $ch = curl_init();
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 20);
  $result = curl_exec($ch);
  curl_close($ch); 
  return $result;
  }

  $result = fetchData("https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/USER ID HERE/media/recent/?access_token=ACCES TOKEN HERE&count=14");


  $result = json_decode($result);
  foreach ($result->data as $post) {
     if(empty($post->caption->text)) {
       // Do Nothing
     }
     else {
        echo '<a class="instagram-unit" target="blank" href="'.$post->link.'">
        <img src="'.$post->images->low_resolution->url.'" alt="'.$post->caption->text.'" width="100%" height="auto" />
        <div class="instagram-desc">'.htmlentities($post->caption->text).' | '.htmlentities(date("F j, Y, g:i a", $post->caption->created_time)).'</div></a>';
     }

  }
?>
```

Resource: [How to get a user's Instagram feed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6311195/how-to-get-a-users-instagram-feed)

Comment: How to get access tokan?