# php for instagram feed

Tags: php, instagram, feed

I'm trying to embed an instagram feed on a webpage. I have gone through the steps on the instagram developer page to get an access token but I don't know what to do with it. Is there php code that you can suggest that I can use to create a feed by adding the user id and the access token?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get a user's Instagram feed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6311195/how-to-get-a-users-instagram-feed)

Answer (score -3, accepted):

[Look at results here](https://www.google.com/search?q=site%3Astackoverflow.com%20php%20for%20instagram%20feed&oq=site%3Astackoverflow.com%20php%20for%20instagram%20feed&aqs=chrome..69i57j69i58.7623j0j1&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8), Google is your friend :)

[Example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6311195/how-to-get-a-users-instagram-feed)

Comment: thanks, i did find that code and replaced the id and the access token with my own but the page came up blank.